# Moving a file to another directory in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
rename $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1] or warn "rename fails: $!\n";
```

When I run `./programe file.txt dir/` it always fails.

What's wrong here?

Comment: What is the error message? Always show complete sample programs with their input and output in case something else is going wrong.

Answer (score 7):

From the perldoc for rename:

> Behavior of this function varies wildly depending on your
>   system implementation.  For example, it will usually not work
>   across file system boundaries, even though the system mv
>   command sometimes compensates for this.  Other restrictions
>   include whether it works on directories, open files, or pre-
>   existing files.  Check perlport and either the rename(2)
>   manpage or equivalent system documentation for details.
>
> For a platform independent "move" function look at the
>   File::Copy module.

So use [File::Copy::move](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy) instead.

Answer (score 5):

rename is expecting a full target path, not just a directory.  Try:

```
./progname file.txt dir/file.txt
```

It would be nice if you would tell what error it failed with...

Comment: It may or may not work on folders depending on the platform. c.f. my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`rename` changes the name of a file, which is not what you're trying to do. You probably want to use the `move` function from [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)